# Un select no me muestra los datos de una tabla mysql en un form

Tags: php, select, tcpdf

De antemano gracias a los creadores de este espacio. Es mi primera publicación.

Comento:
Estoy intentando hacer una consulta dentro de un form para que me despliegue en un select todos los registros de una tabla mysql. Resulta que ya lo he hecho en otros form y me lo muestra, pero en este especifico, que tiene condiciones diferentes adicionales, no lo hace.

En cuales me lo muestra? usando bootstrap normal
En cual no me lo muestra? en un archivo php que tome ya codificado de la web y lo adapté a lo que estoy programando.

**Código con el problema aquí abajo**: (Deseo que me despliegue los inmuebles)

```
<?php

     session_start();

    if(!isset($_SESSION["usuario_logueado"])){

        header('location: ../form/login.php');

    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Edo. Cuenta Inmueble</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- Bootstrap Y JQuery -->
<link href='/exportar_pdf/css/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel="stylesheet">
<script src='/exportar_pdf/css/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='/exportar_pdf/css/pdf_object/pdfobject.js'></script>
<style>
.pdfobject-container { height: 60rem; border: 1rem solid rgba(0,0,0,.1); }
.modal-dialog{background-color: #fff; padding: 20px 15px;}
#cancel{margin: 5px; display: block;}
.cargando{position: absolute;width: 30px;right: -40px;top: -2px;}
.hide{display: none;}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="slide_uno col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <h2 class="text-center">Estado de Cuenta Inmueble</h2>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <!--<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">-->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div id="datatable_length">
                            <!-- SELECCION DEL INMUEBLE -->

                      <div class="form-group col-md-2">     

                      <div class="col">
                      <label for="option">Inmueble:</label> 
                      <?php
                      $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
                      $path .= "conexion_inst.php";
                      include($path); 
                               $query=mysqli_query($mysqli,"select id, id_inmueble, propietario from inmuebles order by id");
                     ?>
                      <select class="form-control col-md-4" name="inmueble" id="inmueble">
                          <?php while($datos=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){?> 
                             <option value="<?php echo $datos['id_inmueble']?>"> <?php 
                             echo $datos['id_inmueble'];
                             ?></option>
                            <?php 
                            }

                            ?>
                       </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                            <!-- RANGO DE FECHAS A BUSCAR Y EXPORTAR -->
                            <label style="font-weight: normal;">Desde: <input class="form-control" type="date" id="bd-desde"/></label>
                            <label style="font-weight: normal;">Hasta: <input class="form-control" type="date" id="bd-hasta"/></label>
                            <button id="rango_fecha" class="btn-sm btn-primary">Buscar</button>
                            <!-- BOTON PARA EXPORTAR EL RANGO DE FECHAS -->
                            <a onClick="javascript:reportePDF();" class="btn-sm btn-danger" style="padding: 8px 15px; cursor: pointer; position: relative;">Exportar PDF<span><img src='/exportar_pdf/cargando.gif' class="cargando hide"></span></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">  
                <div class="row">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th width="5">Fila</th>
                        <th width="20">En Banco</th>
                        <th width="20">Inmueble</th>
                        <th width="20">Monto</th>
                        <th width="20">Referencia</th>
                        <th width="60">Observaciones</th>
                        <th width="6">Banco</th>
                        <th width="20">Tipo</th>
                        <th width="20">Documento</th>
                        <th width="20">Saldo Inmueble</th>
                        <th width="20">Procesado</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <!-- CONTENEDOR DONDE SE IMPRIMEN LA CONSULTA POR FECHAS -->
                    <tbody id="actualizar">
                        <?php include('/php/reportes/estado_de_cuenta/includes/imprimir_bitacora.php'); ?>
                    </tbody>
                </div>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="ver-pdf" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="x_panel">
        <div class="x_title">
            <h2 class="text-center">Reporte Generado</h2>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>

         <div id="view_pdf"></div>
            <a id="cancel" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancelar</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function busca_por_fecha(){    
    $('#rango_fecha').on('click',function(){
        var desde = $('#bd-desde').val();
        var hasta = $('#bd-hasta').val();
        var url = '/php/reportes/estado_de_cuenta/dao/busca_por_fecha.php';
        $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:url,
        data:'desde='+desde+'&hasta='+hasta,
        success: function(datos){
            $('#actualizar').html(datos);
        }
    });
    return false;
    });
})();

function reportePDF(){
    var desde = $('#bd-desde').val();
    var hasta = $('#bd-hasta').val();
    var url = '/php/reportes/estado_de_cuenta/dao/exportar_pdf.php';
    $('.cargando').removeClass('hide');
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:url,
        data:'desde='+desde+'&hasta='+hasta,
        success: function(datos){
            $('.cargando').addClass('hide');
            $('#ver-pdf').modal({
                show:true,
                backdrop:'static'
            }); 
            PDFObject.embed('/php/reportes/estado_de_cuenta/temp/reporte.pdf', '#view_pdf');
        }
    });
    return false;
}


</script>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<script src='/exportar_pdf/css/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Has depurado algo? Acostumbra a usar `var_dump` para depurar los datos que esperas. Algo que no veo, de entrada, es dónde te conectas a la base de datos. Eso es lo primero, sin conexión no obtendrás datos. Dinos dónde te conectas.

Comment: OK, ya vi donde incluyes la conexión. Entonces depura los datos, después de esto: `<?php while($datos=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){?>`  pon un `var_dump($datos);` para depurar si la consulta está trayendo datos realemente y qué estructura tienen.

Comment: Listo, listo. Por fin, lo logré. Resulta que la conexion la tengo en el directorio raiz en el servidor, por lo que me faltaba colocar el /. Es decir: $path .= "/conexion_inst.php";